# What is the best way to move Windows files to Ubuntu 20?

Tags: file, ssh, samba

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20 on my new desktop machine.
I want to move all my files from Windows 10 (about 70GB) to the linux machine.
I've tried nitro, but it seems it works only up to Ubuntu 18.
I'd prefer to use a UI to copy.
What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the program [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php). The program has a nice GUI and is easy to use. It is also possible to use some cloud versions, like Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.